# Are mongodb cursor serializable (node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, high-availability

My aim is to support paginated queries while achieving "consistency" (not the real meaning here but basically when a user asks for the 5 firsts and later ask the 5 following, if there was an addition in the meantime I don't want the 5th to be in the second query)

My first idea is when a user wants the first page I start a mongodb query, store the cursor in memory and then get the first five. Then when the user wants the next page I continue the cursor (since it was saved in memory).

In theory it works great but it fails when there are multiple servers since they can't share memory.

So my main question is, how can I serialize the cursors (so I can share them on a Redis server for example)

Or, is there a better way to achieve my goal

Thank you for your help

Comment: You cannot serialize the cursors in that manner. While serializing only the result set is returned. Why not store the last accessed object's _id in Redis server / session, and query for 5 objects having _id greater than one accessed before.

Comment: It only works if the query is ordered by id :/ Which not the case for most queries. But thank you very much !